# in Asp.net MVC, Do I need to update Entity if I change my view column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm, entity

I find this site is very interesting and very helpful. I came up with this doubt while programming a project in asp.net mvc. I had to remove few columns from a view which I was using to pull data from the database back to my presentation layer. After removing those columns, I build my project and there were no errors. When I ran it, my project broke with error saying missing related columns as Entity was not changed.

But, my question is that is it necessary that every time I need to update my entity model?. What if I deploy my project in production and then had to remove one column from the view? It will be a hell of task for me If I had to update model, build and deploy it back again on production. Is there a simple solution for this?? thanks for your help

Comment: Yep, you need to update your EF if you change your Database. It's no different than removing a property from an object and then hoping to reference that property in your code.

Comment: Thanks Darren, but I remember I changed a view by removing some columns which some other programmer had created and when I launched the website, it worked without any problem. So this created a doubt in my mind as whether is there any way that entity automatically considers this change and reflects it back.

Comment: You will find it will build and run fine, though at the time your code tries to reference the columns that were removed it will break. It's a Runtime error. 
It's always better and safer to update your EF when you change the Database. If you do this first, you can then find the places where these columns are being referenced as it will not build in debug.

Comment: Why didn't you just remove it from the view? it could be that that property will be needed in the future

Comment: And such situations are usually easy to fix when your domain classes are mapped via fluent api. Than you totally control over the situation

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the entity model every time the database structure changes, what you need to do is to decouple the EF model from the MVC project, if you don't what to work with Ioc, a simpler approach whould be to place the EF model in a separate assembly, when the database changes, rebuild the assembly and deploy it on the server, this way you don't need to rebuild the entire MVC.